# Variable tablename inside fetch and forall insert rowtype

Tags: plsql, forall

I open a cursor, and do a fetch bulk collect. The problem comes when I do a FORALL to INSERT all records inside a table, because this table is a variable. This is the code:

```
TYPE DST_TYPE IS TABLE OF DST_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
TYPE CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

v_srcTable := 'my_src_table'; /* Dynamic Variable */
v_dstTable := 'my_dst_table'; /* Dynamic Variable */
v_partition := 'my_partition'; /* Dynamic Variable */
v_dstRecords DST_TYPE;
v_Cursor CURSOR;

OPEN v_Cursor FOR 
           'SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (TT 2) */ field1,field2,field3,...,field50 FROM' || v_srcTable || ' TT ';
    LOOP
        FETCH v_Cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_dstRecords LIMIT 1000;
        FORALL i in 1 .. v_dstRecords.COUNT
        INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO v_dstTable PARTITION(v_partition) MT VALUES v_dstRecords(i); 

        COMMIT;             
        EXIT WHEN v_Cursor%NOTFOUND; 
    END LOOP;
CLOSE v_Cursor;
```

This fails because v_dstTable is not a valid table (valid table is "my_dst_table"). So, if I want to parse the table name, I need to change that for "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INSERT..:" syntax. The problem is, if I use this syntax, I cannot pass a rowtype in VALUES

```
v_SQL := 'INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO ' || v_dstTable || ' PARTITION(' || v_partition || ') MT VALUES :1';

FORALL i in 1 .. v_dstRecords.COUNT
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL USING v_dstRecords(i);
```

The only alternative I see is to pass all the parameters of the rowtype as bind variables, but there are 50 parameters...

```
v_SQL := 'INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO ' || v_dstTable || ' PARTITION(' || v_partition || ') MT VALUES (:1,:2,:3,...,:50)';

FORALL i in 1 .. v_dstRecords.COUNT
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL USING v_dstRecords(i).field1, v_dstRecords(i).field2, ..., v_dstRecords(i).field50;
```

Is there any way to do this without using syntax with bind variables? If you have only 1 parameter is ok, but if you have 50...

Thanks

Comment: It would probably be simpler just to construct the whole `insert into t2 select ... from t1` dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but that sql does not limit the amount of records, and there are millions of records, so there may be undo  problems. With bulk collect and cursor, I can limit each loop to 1.000 records for example.

Comment: I would first confirm that undo really are an issue, as `insert` (especially direct path) is typically light on undo compared to `delete` or `update`. If it is, and if provisioning sufficient resources for a routine workload is not an option, then perhaps you could split the rowset into ranges of a numeric ID column, or else do something with global temp tables.

Comment: The undo was a problem when there were more operations at the same time, as it took much time to finish the inserts, and we got ORA errors. I´ve used the syntax with bind variables, and it works perfect. Not pretty code, but it´s very efficient (the inserts are very fast now).